# Computing the norm and trace or the conjugate

Tags: normed-spaces, rationalising-denominator

Express $1/(1+2(^3√7)-5(^3√49))$ in the form $a+b(^3√7)+c(^3√49)$

I have a couple ideas, but I may be wrong:

1. I want to compute the norm of the given expression. My result is $x^3 - 3x^2 + 33x +12,191$, but that's not what I want.
2. I want to compute the given expression by taking the conjugate of the denominator, namely $(1+2(^3√7)-5(^3√49)$. However, I do not know how I could do it with a trinomial. If it was a binomial, I would have no problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Carefully compute the product $\left(1+2(^3√7)-5(^3√49)\right) \left(a+b(^3√7)+c(^3√49) \right),$  then solve for $a,b,c$ integers such that the result is a rational integer (no cube roots remain).

Answer (score 1):

there is a conjugate available, it amounts to factoring $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz$  but throwing in coefficients.

Take $  t^3 = d ,$  where your $d=7,$ anyway the cube root will be called $t.$

$$  \left( x+ty+t^2 z \right) \left( x^2 + t^2 y^2 + t^4 z^2 - t^3 yz - t^2 z x - t x y  \right)   $$
$$  = x^3 + t^3 y^3 + t^6 z^3 - 3 t^3 xyz$$
$$  = x^3 + d y^3 + d^2 z^3 - 3dxyz  $$